# Sugars for Mushroom cultures

Tags: mushrooms

I have been trying to grow mushrooms from liquid cultures this year with some success.  I have read about people using different sources of sugar such as honey, malt extract, or molasses in boiled water, and I was wondering if one form of sugar is better for growing particular types of mushrooms.